# How can I make div with 'position: fixed' stop between two elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is there any possible way to make div with postion: fixed stop beetween two DOM elements?

What I want is
place ".fixedDiv" between last div ".break" and "#footer" after ".fixedDiv" reaches the ".break" (between 'ABOVE' and 'BELOW').

I have already tried to get the bottom position of last div and set $('.fixedDiv').css('top', bottomPostion+'px') but this doesn't work for me.
I'm fresh to jQuery and I have no idea how to solve my problem.
What I have already is:

```js
function checkOffset() {
  var fix = $('.fixedDiv');
  var position = $(document).scrollTop() + window.innerHeight;
  var footerTop = $('#footer').offset().top;
  if (position < footerTop) {
    fix.css('bottom', '10px');
  } else {
    fix.css('bottom', (15 + (position - footerTop)) + 'px');
  }
}
$(document).ready(checkOffset);
$(document).scroll(checkOffset);
```

```css
.fixedDiv {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #000;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: #fff000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div>div</div>
  <div>div</div>
  <div>div</div>
  <div>div</div>
  <div>div</div>
  <div>div</div>
  <div>div</div>
  <div>div</div>
  <div>div</div>
  <div>div</div>
  <div>div</div>
  <div>div</div>
  <div>div</div>
  <div>div</div>
  <div>div</div>
  <div>div</div>
  <div>div</div>
  <div>div</div>
  <div>div</div>
  <div>div</div>
  <div>div</div>
  <div>div</div>
  <div>div</div>
  <div>div</div>
  <div>div</div>
  <div>div</div>
  <div>div</div>
  <div>div</div>
  <div>div</div>
  <div>div</div>
  <div>div</div>
  <div>div</div>
  <div>div</div>
  <div>div</div>
  <div>div</div>
  <div>div</div>
  <div>div</div>
  <div>div</div>
  <div>div</div>
  <div>div</div>
  <div>div</div>
  <div>div</div>
  <div>div</div>
  <div>div</div>
  <div>div</div>
  <div>div</div>
  <div class="break">BELOW</div>
  <div class="fixedDiv"></div>
</div>
<footer id="footer">ABOVE</footer>
```

[And what I want is this](https://jsfiddle.net/gmzu2z8u/5/)

Comment: I find it hard to imagine what you're expecting to achieve, could you make a quick mockup of the desired layout?

Comment: Not sure what is your expected behaviour but for sure you should use `$(window).scroll(checkOffset);` instead of `$(document).scroll(checkOffset);`, and `$(window).scrollTop()` instead of `$(document).scrollTop()`. This would be more browser friendly

Comment: Thank you. I'm wondering if there's any possible way to place .fixedDiv between the last element and footer. I have page with few tables and when the .fixedDiv reaches the bottom of last table it should appear between the bottom of the table and footer.

Comment: Something like this --> https://jsfiddle.net/gmzu2z8u/4/ ?

Comment: Yes, thank you so much!

Comment: I'll post it as an answer then - since you found it useful. You can really thank me by marking it as accepted :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, you needed to reset the `position` property value to `relative` at the point already correctly specified by your `.scroll()` method.

I used classes to do this, as it allows you better control over specified styles declared and generally a better alternative practice to inlining styles.

**Code Snippet Demonstration:**

```js
function checkOffset() {
   var fix = $('.dynamicDiv');
   var position = $(window).scrollTop() + window.innerHeight;
   var footerTop = $('#footer').offset().top;
   if (position < footerTop) {
     fix.removeClass('relativeDiv').addClass('fixedDiv');
   } else {
     fix.removeClass('fixedDiv').addClass('relativeDiv');
   }
 }
$(document).ready(checkOffset);
$(window).scroll(checkOffset);
```

```css
.dynamicDiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #000;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  transition: .7s;
}

.relativeDiv {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0;
}

.fixedDiv {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 10px;
}

#footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: #fff000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <div>div</div>
    <div>div</div>
    <div>div</div>
    <div>div</div>
    <div>div</div>
    <div>div</div>
    <div>div</div>
    <div>div</div>
    <div>div</div>
    <div>div</div>
    <div>div</div>
    <div>div</div>
    <div>div</div>
    <div>div</div>
    <div>div</div>
    <div>div</div>
    <div>div</div>
    <div>div</div>
    <div>div</div>
    <div>div</div>
    <div>div</div>
    <div>div</div>
    <div>div</div>
    <div>div</div>
    <div>div</div>
    <div>div</div>
    <div>div</div>
    <div>div</div>
    <div>div</div>
    <div>div</div>
    <div>div</div>
    <div>div</div>
    <div>div</div>
    <div>div</div>
    <div>div</div>
    <div>div</div>
    <div>div</div>
    <div>div</div>
    <div>div</div>
    <div>div</div>
    <div>div</div>
    <div>div</div>
    <div>div</div>
    <div>div</div>
    <div>div</div>
    <div>div</div>
    <div class="break">BELOW</div>
    <div class="dynamicDiv"></div>
</div>
<footer id="footer">ABOVE</footer>
```

[Updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gmzu2z8u/4/)